# Avoid unnecessary bindings in angular-js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of objects, with two properties: `name` and `status`. `name` does not change, while `status` does.

I am displaying them in the follwoing fashion:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in objects">
   <div>{{obj.name}}</div>
   <div>{{obj.status}}</div>
<div>
```

But clearly the data binding created for `obj.name` is unnecessary. 
How can I avoid its creation (while still having a binding created for `status`?

Comment: can you explain your question

Comment: Check out https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce